# Django, passing parameters to form field from fromfield method of custom model field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-the-form-field-for-a-model-field) :

> All of the kwargs dictionary is passed directly to the form field’s __init__() method

```
def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    # This is a fairly standard way to set up some defaults
    # while letting the caller override them.
    defaults = {'form_class': MyFormField}
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    return super(HandField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

If MyFormField is :

```
class GeopositionField(forms.MultiValueField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items(): # this doesn't print anything
             print name 
             print value

         self.widget = GeopositionWidget()
         fields = (
           forms.DecimalField(label=_('latitude')),
           forms.DecimalField(label=_('longitude')),
         )
         super(GeopositionField, self).__init__(fields, required=False)
```

How could I pass parameters to the formfield and get it on **init** method ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern from the documentation. Create the dictionary and pass it to the super's `formfield` method.

```
class GeopositionField(forms.MultiValueField):    
    #...
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        # get the values you want to pass to init
        defaults = {'your_kwarg_key': your_kwarg_value}
        defaults['your_other_kwarg_key'] = your_other_kwarg_value
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(HandField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

I don't think the docs are saying that the results of the `formfield` method are passed to `__init__` method, and I can't see it happening like that in the source code.

I think the docs just say that all the `kwargs` are passed to `__init__` (as you'd expect), so you can change the field class by passing a `form_class` argument to `__init__` - however if you'd like to create the field class dynamically, you can override the `formfield` method.